# Out of range decimal for column 'Price' at row 1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to populate the fields of a database and I keep getting errors no matter how I change my decimal value. I had my decimal first set to (2,2) and then I changed it to (4,2)-- this was after I got some feedback and did some research. Any help would be appreciate it. Thank you.

My insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Ingredient(Name, Price)
values ('Chocolate', '10.50');
```

And the database:

```
 -- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema BrendaStore
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `BrendaStore` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema BrendaStore
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `BrendaStore` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
USE `BrendaStore` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Vendor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Vendor` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vendor` (
  `idVendor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVendor`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Shop`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Shop` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Shop` (
  `idShop` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idShop`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Product` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Product` (
  `idProduct` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ProductPrice` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `Shop_idShop` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`),
  INDEX `fk_Product_Shop1_idx` (`Shop_idShop` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_Shop1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shop_idShop`)
    REFERENCES `Shop` (`idShop`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Recipe`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Recipe` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Recipe` (
  `idRecipe` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IngredientAmount` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Product_idProduct` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRecipe`),
  INDEX `fk_Recipe_Product1_idx` (`Product_idProduct` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Recipe_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_idProduct`)
    REFERENCES `Product` (`idProduct`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Ingredient`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Ingredient` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ingredient` (
  `idIngredient` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Price` DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL,
  `Vendor_idVendor` INT NOT NULL,
  `Recipe_idRecipe` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_idProduct` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idIngredient`),
  INDEX `fk_Ingredient_Vendor_idx` (`Vendor_idVendor` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Ingredient_Recipe1_idx` (`Recipe_idRecipe` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Ingredient_Product1_idx` (`Product_idProduct` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ingredient_Vendor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Vendor_idVendor`)
    REFERENCES `Vendor` (`idVendor`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ingredient_Recipe1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Recipe_idRecipe`)
    REFERENCES `Recipe` (`idRecipe`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ingredient_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_idProduct`)
    REFERENCES `Product` (`idProduct`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Client`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Client` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Client` (
  `idClient` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idClient`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Purchase`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Purchase` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Purchase` (
  `idPurchase` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PurchaseDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `PurchaseAmount` DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL,
  `Client_idClient` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPurchase`),
  INDEX `fk_Purchase_Client1_idx` (`Client_idClient` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Purchase_Client1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Client_idClient`)
    REFERENCES `Client` (`idClient`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Orders`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Orders` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Orders` (
  `idOrders` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Price` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOrders`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Employee` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee` (
  `idEmployee` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEmployee`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Shop_has_Employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Shop_has_Employee` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Shop_has_Employee` (
  `Shop_idShop` INT NOT NULL,
  `Employee_idEmployee` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Shop_idShop`, `Employee_idEmployee`),
  INDEX `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Employee1_idx` (`Employee_idEmployee` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Shop1_idx` (`Shop_idShop` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Shop1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shop_idShop`)
    REFERENCES `Shop` (`idShop`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Employee_idEmployee`)
    REFERENCES `Employee` (`idEmployee`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Ingredient_has_Orders`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Ingredient_has_Orders` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ingredient_has_Orders` (
  `Ingredient_idIngredient` INT NOT NULL,
  `Orders_idOrders` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ingredient_idIngredient`, `Orders_idOrders`),
  INDEX `fk_Ingredient_has_Orders_Orders1_idx` (`Orders_idOrders` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Ingredient_has_Orders_Ingredient1_idx` (`Ingredient_idIngredient` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ingredient_has_Orders_Ingredient1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Ingredient_idIngredient`)
    REFERENCES `Ingredient` (`idIngredient`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Ingredient_has_Orders_Orders1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Orders_idOrders`)
    REFERENCES `Orders` (`idOrders`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Product_has_Purchase`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Product_has_Purchase` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Product_has_Purchase` (
  `Product_idProduct` INT NOT NULL,
  `Purchase_idPurchase` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_idProduct`, `Purchase_idPurchase`),
  INDEX `fk_Product_has_Purchase_Purchase1_idx` (`Purchase_idPurchase` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Product_has_Purchase_Product1_idx` (`Product_idProduct` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_has_Purchase_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_idProduct`)
    REFERENCES `Product` (`idProduct`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_has_Purchase_Purchase1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Purchase_idPurchase`)
    REFERENCES `Purchase` (`idPurchase`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: use `Price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,` in ingrediant assuming no price can be more than 99.99 the 1st number is the TOTAL number of digits in the number.  the 2nd is the number of decimals.  so you can't have a price of over .99. and get rid of the ticks around the price.  it's a number not a string.

Comment: You need default values for the columns that you're not including in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: You didn't show which error you're getting. Anyway note: since `Ingredient.Price` is `DECIMAL(2,2)` you shouldn't wrap the value between quotes in your insert statement. Write it so: `INSERT INTO Ingredient(Name, Price) values ('Chocolate', 10.50);`.

Comment: also true, NOT NULL values must have a value !

Comment: @cfreed.  I think the title is the error message.

Comment: I guess since those are foreign keys, your real query fills them in.

Comment: I get that error with `DECIMAL(2,2)`, but changing it to `DECIMAL(4,2)` fixes it. But if you have prices higher than `99.99`, you'll need to make it larger.

Comment: It works here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d019

Comment: @xQbert Oops, didn't pay attention: you're right.

Comment: I'm still having issues, actually right now I'm getting another error--cannot update child row